# Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.VirtualPathExtension'

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, sap-dotnet-connector, .net-standard-2.1

I am using SAPNCo.dll Net Core 3.1.
I have not created instince RfcConfigParameters.

```
public RfcCongfigParameters GetParameters()
    {
        try
        {
            var instance=new RfcCongfigParameters();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in _parameters)
            {
                instance.Add(p.Key, p.Value);
            }

            return instance;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

> Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.VirtualPathExtension' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

[Exception Detail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X19YY.png)

I tested Console .Net Core 3.1 Project.

thank u helping.

Comment: [this class is .net framework/mono only](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ServiceModel.Activation.VirtualPathExtension) and not available in .net core. Change your project to .net framework 4.8